# No parameterless constructor defined for this object error in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, controller, inversion-of-control

I want to use Dependency Injection on AccountController but i am getting this error "No parameterless constructor defined for this object" when login.Is this a true approach that using Dependency Injection while loginig.A lot of person use this approach on login control.

```
public interface IAuthProvider {
    bool Authenticate(string username, string password);
}

public class AccountController : Controller {
    IAuthProvider authProvider;

    public AccountController(IAuthProvider auth) {
        authProvider = auth;
    }

    public ViewResult Login() {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl) {

        if (ModelState.IsValid) {
            if (authProvider.Authenticate(model.UserName, model.Password)) {
                return Redirect(returnUrl ?? Url.Action("Index", "Admin"));
            } else {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Incorrect username or password");
                return View();
            }
        } else {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the code that you use to map the `IAuthProvider` to an implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you're using Unity. If so, you don't need a parameterless constructor. When registering your instance you should use an [InjectionConstructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.injectionconstructor.aspx). With that Unity can resolve the correct constructor.